# What is the correct way to update a case in a new sql migration file?

Tags: sql, mysql

I currently have an MySQL migration file:

```
INSERT INTO consumption_report_log_entry
SELECT
unhex(md5(uuid())),
cr.id AS consumption_report_id,
unit_id,
u.name AS unit_name,
cru.tenancy_id AS tenancy_id,
l.name AS tenancy_name,
CASE
    WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.closed_date THEN 'CLOSED'
    WHEN cr.collection_date > t.rent_end_date THEN 'POSTTERMINATION'
    WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.termination_date THEN 'TERMINATED'
    WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.rent_start_date THEN 'ACTIVE'
    ELSE 'PENDING'
END AS tenancy_status,
tenancy_number,
rent_start_date,
rent_end_date,
l.email,
current_aconto,
new_aconto,
paid_in_advance,
actual_to_be_paid,
difference_to_be_paid,
cr.collection_date
FROM consumption_report cr
LEFT JOIN consumption_report_unit cru ON cru.consumption_report_id = cr.id
LEFT JOIN unit u ON cru.unit_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN tenancy t ON cru.tenancy_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN tenancy_tenant tt ON tt.tenancy_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN legal_entity l ON tt.tenant_id = l.id;
```

I need to make a new migration query where I change some of the cases as well as the else statement. Normally I would alter columns like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1,
WHERE condition;
```

But what is the update procedure for cases?

Would this be the correct approach?

```
UPDATE consumption_report_log_entry
SET tenancy_status = CASE
WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.closed_date THEN 'CLOSED'
WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.rent_end_date THEN 'POSTTERMINATION'
WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.rent_start_date THEN 'ACTIVE'
ELSE 'EMPTY' END
```

Comment: Yes, your update looks fine.  Have you tried testing it yet?

Comment: (on a staging database)

Answer (score 1):

To update the `tenancy_status` in the `consumption_report_log_entry` table using a CASE statement, as shown in your example, requires joining the necessary tables to access the columns used in the CASE conditions. The example you provided does not include these joins, which are crucial for the query to work correctly.

Given that you're referencing columns from other tables in the CASE statement, you'll need to join the `consumption_report_log_entry` table with those tables. Assuming `consumption_report_log_entry` has foreign keys or other joinable fields to link back to the necessary data, the query needs to incorporate these joins.

```sql
UPDATE consumption_report_log_entry crle
JOIN consumption_report cr ON crle.consumption_report_id = cr.id
JOIN consumption_report_unit cru ON cru.consumption_report_id = cr.id
JOIN unit u ON cru.unit_id = u.id
JOIN tenancy t ON cru.tenancy_id = t.id
JOIN tenancy_tenant tt ON tt.tenancy_id = t.id
JOIN legal_entity l ON tt.tenant_id = l.id
SET crle.tenancy_status = CASE
    WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.closed_date THEN 'CLOSED'
    WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.rent_end_date THEN 'POSTTERMINATION'
    WHEN cr.collection_date >= t.rent_start_date THEN 'ACTIVE'
    ELSE 'EMPTY'
END
```